# Editable list of items GridView or DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a requirement to show list of data items (editable) without any headers,which is the best way to go in MVVM ..GridView or DataGrid???? I should be able to select individual item for editing and I need to do lot of styling on each item.

Comment: So... where is the question mark?

Comment: @NikitaBrizhak Question marks for you,Its an irony that SO users are so advance that they compile everything for errors:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both the DataGrid and GridView controls are derived from the WebControl class. Although it has a similar object model to that of the DataGrid control, the GridView control also has a number of new features and advantages over the DataGrid control, which include:

Richer design-time capabilities.

Improved data source binding capabilities.

Automatic handling of sorting, paging, updates, and deletes.

Additional column types and design-time column operations.

A Customized pager user interface (UI) with the PagerTemplate property.

Differences between the GridView control and the DataGrid control include:

Different custom-paging support.

Different event models.

Try this link - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/05yye6k9(v=vs.100).aspx